Setting up google ads purchase for woocommerce but I don's get the correct data back in the dataLayer
I have a google ads tag that is tracking my purchase for a woocommerce website.
But inside the dataLayer I don't get the value or ordernumber back.
I put this code inside my function.php:
function thankyou_page_tracking_code() {
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) {
        return;
    }
?>
<script> gtag('event', 'conversion', { 'send_to': 'Here i write my number', 'value': 0.0, 'currency': 'EUR', 'transaction_id': '' }); </script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'thankyou_page_tracking_code' );

But I don't see anything inside my dataLayer.
I do get an error that says (in dutch): 
Variabele is als onwaar geretourneerd vanwege een onbekende fout tijdens de uitvoering 
Total Ecommerce Items Value (price * quantity) 
Which in english is: 
Variable returned false due to an unknown error during execution 
Total Ecommerce Items Value (price * quantity)
I tried multiple things but something like this:
function thankyou_page_tracking_code() {
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Haal de order ID op uit de URL
    $order_id = isset( $_GET['order-received'] ) ? $_GET['order-received'] : '';

    // Haal de WooCommerce order op
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if ( ! $order ) {
        return; // Als de order niet bestaat, stop dan
    }

    // Haal de order totaal en valuta op
    $order_total = $order->get_total();
    $currency = get_woocommerce_currency();

    // Voeg de Google Ads tracking code toe met de juiste transaction_id, value en currency
    ?>
    <script>
        gtag('event', 'conversion', {
            'send_to': 'here i write my number',
            'value': <?php echo $order_total; ?>,
            'currency': '<?php echo $currency; ?>',
            'transaction_id': '<?php echo $order->get_id(); ?>'
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'thankyou_page_tracking_code' );`

This makes the webshop not even go to purchase page.
Anybody an idea?

In your 2nd code attempt, $_GET['order-received'] will not allow you to get the order ID.
Instead try the following:
function thankyou_page_tracking_code() {
    global $wp;

    // Exit if not on order received page or no order ID available
    if ( ! isset($wp->query_vars['order-received']) ) {
        return; 
    }
    $order_id = absint($wp->query_vars['order-received']); // The order ID
    $order    = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // The WC_Order object

    // Exit if $order is not a WC_Order object
    if ( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) return; 
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': 'here i write my number',
        'value': <?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>,
        'currency': '<?php echo $order->get_currency(); ?>',
        'transaction_id': '<?php echo $order_id; ?>'
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'thankyou_page_tracking_code', 5 );

It should work.
